# "Treatment" vs. "therapy"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

We are going to establish a company in order to commercialize a stuttering treatment/therapy program.

The treatment/therapy is really effective and backed by a lot of scientific research.

In our recent discussions, some disagreement has come up whether to market it as the "XYZ stuttering treatment" or the "XYZ stuttering therapy".

On one hand, calling our product the "XYZ stuttering treatment" might be advantageous, because in all the research literature it is referred to as such.

On the other hand, calling it the "XYZ stuttering therapy" could be better, because all the competition markets/offers their programs as "therapies", and having the term "therapy" appears to be more serious and seems to imply effectiveness. Also, the word "therapy" appears to be more international, which could help if we offer the program abroad.

I'm not a native speaker though, so I wanted to hear your opinion and feedback.

What's really the difference between "treatment" and "therapy"?

Would you rather recommend calling it the  "XYZ stuttering treatment" or the "XYZ stuttering therapy"? Why?

Comment: Therapy is what one needs; treatment is what one gets, which may or may not be therapeutic.

Comment: This question probably belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) because it is about communication in everyday English, and is not about the academic study of English Language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Therapy* is preferable in this context as it appears to be a *treatment programme*. *Treatment* would be preferred if you were giving a specific drug.

***Therapy*** is defined in the dictionary as

> the treatment of disease or disorders, as by some remedial, rehabilitating, or curative process: speech therapy.

***Treatment*** is defined as

> management in the application of medicines, surgery, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, in the literature it's referred to as the "XYZ stuttering treatment program". So you think we should market it as the "XYZ stuttering therapy"?

Comment: definitely yes :)

Comment: Stuttering Therapy is googled far more often that stuttering treatment, so this is a good answer from that viewpoint as well: http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=stuttering%20therapy%2C%20stuttering%20treatment&geo=US&date=today%2012-m&cmpt=q

Answer (score 0):

A therapy is some sort of cure: it is a treatment which makes brings about some kind of healing improvement.

A treatment is not necessarily something which heals.

Treatment can refer to a behavior with regard to something or someone which describes the attitude, rather than any lasting effect: how does your boss treat you?

Treatment can be bad: "ill treatment" or "mistreatment". You can treat something or someone well, or you can treat something or someone badly. But there is no "ill therapy".

A beneficial treatment, furthermore, isn't necessarily some sort of healing. A permanent wave is a hair treatment, yet is not necessary for health in any way. Inanimate objects can be treated beneficially. For instance, applying a waterproofing substance to a tent is a treatment.  Sewage is treated so that the resulting water can be released into the environment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So you think we should market it as the "XYZ stuttering therapy"?

Comment: I would say so, if you are confident that your treatment actually improves the stuttering. I.e. is "therapeutic"!